# DataTables not showing search,sort,and filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

**Hello guys can you help me solve this? I have 2 different modal on the same page. The first modal shows search and filter**

[image: click to view first modal]

but the other modals cannot show anything, only the content
[image]

```
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
        $('.modal-child').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            var modalParent = $(this).attr('data-modal-parent');
            $(modalParent).css('opacity', 0);
        });

        $('.modal-child').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            var modalParent = $(this).attr('data-modal-parent');
            $(modalParent).css('opacity', 1);
        });


    } );
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you provide all your HTML code with the working modals? It would help us debug your question and give you a better answer.

Comment: are you using api? also check for the table headers. i think you have an issue with showing your table data.. there is no table headers on your second table. check for table id. in some cases duplicate table id may not works..

Answer (score 0):

The first modal you are using `$('#example').DataTable();`

The second modal you are not using `$('#second').DataTable();`

So, you must add for the second modal.

Answer (score 0):

The tables should have different id. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table1').DataTable();
    $('#table2').DataTable();
  });
</script>
...
<table id="table1" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
...
<table id="table2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```